# CSS image and text issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the texts in the `div class="caption"` with the image on top of them `class="img"`, but while the transition is ending, the text goes on top of the image. I tried with `"overflow: hidden;"` and `"overflow: visible"`, but it works only at the beginning of the animation.

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  border-radius: 85px;
}

li:hover .img {
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, -80px);
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
  border-radius: 85px;
}


/*CAPTION AND GAME TITLE*/

.caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover .caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="games/tictactoe.html"><img id="picture" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="TicTacToe"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Tic Tac Toe</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/battleship.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="battleShip"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Battle Ship</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/pythagoreantable.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="pythagoreantable"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Pythagorean Table</h3>
        <h2>Tool</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transforming the caption, it becomes the root element of a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), and since it's after the `a` tag (the parent of `.img`), it goes over the image.

Set the `a` above the `.caption`:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  border-radius: 85px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

li:hover .img {
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, -80px);
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
  border-radius: 85px;
}


/*CAPTION AND GAME TITLE*/

.caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover .caption {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px, 70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="games/tictactoe.html"><img id="picture" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="TicTacToe"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Tic Tac Toe</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/battleship.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="battleShip"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Battle Ship</h3>
        <h2>Game for two players</h2>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="games/pythagoreantable.html"><img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="pythagoreantable"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="gametitle">Pythagorean Table</h3>
        <h2>Tool</h2>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```